# With Conditions, Can we say that, $\partial A\subset B$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f,g$ are Continuous function ($f>0$) and

1. $0\le\alpha<\beta$.
2. $A = \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{R},f(x) \leqslant \alpha g(x)} \right\}$.
3. $\partial A \subseteq \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{R},f(x) = \alpha g(x)} \right\}$.
4. $B = \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{R},f(x) \leqslant \beta g(x)} \right\}$.
5. $\partial A$ is boundary of $A$.

Can we say that, $\partial A\subset B$?

Comment: @Marc -Why is true?

Comment: Wouldn't you also want $g>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint to make things more simple:

If $f,g$ are continuous functions and moreover $f$ is a positive function then $h$ prescribed by:$$x\mapsto\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$$ is a continuous function.

Also discern the cases $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha>0$.

---

**edit**:

Suppose that $\alpha>0$.

Then the continuity of $h$ tells us that  $A=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid \frac1{\alpha}\leq h(x)\}$ is closed.

Consequently $\partial A\subseteq\text{cl}(A)=A=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid \frac1{\alpha}\leq h(x)\}$.

The continuity of $h$ tells us that  $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid \frac1{\alpha}<h(x)\}\subseteq A$ is open.

Consequently $\partial A\cap\{x\in\mathbb R\mid \frac1{\alpha}<h(x)\}=\varnothing $.

Proved is now that $\partial A\subseteq\{x\in\mathbb R\mid \frac1{\alpha}=h(x)\}$.

Also we have $\frac1{\beta}<\frac1{\alpha}$ so that $A=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid \frac1{\alpha}\leq h(x)\}\subseteq\{x\in\mathbb R\mid \frac1{\beta}\leq h(x)\}=B$.

As said the case $\alpha=0$ must be treated separately. I leave that to you.

Comment: Please more guide.

Comment: Do you understand how you can simplify? You are working with two functions now, but you can make it one. E.g. $f(x)\leq\alpha g(x)$ can be replaced by $1\leq\alpha h(x)$.

Comment: Is it true that $\partial A \subseteq \left\{ {x \in R,\frac{1}{\alpha } = h(x)} \right\} \subseteq \left\{ {x \in R,\frac{1}{\alpha } \leqslant h(x)} \right\} \subset \left\{ {x \in R,\frac{1}{\beta } \leqslant h(x)} \right\} = B$

Comment: Yes if $\alpha>0$. If $h(x)>\frac1{\alpha}$ then you find a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $h(y)\in A$ for each $y\in N$ and if $h(x)<\frac1{\alpha}$ then you find a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $h(y)\notin A$ for each $y\in N$. In both cases $x\notin\partial A$.

Comment: Which neighborhood of $x$?